# an error occurs when starting a game with unity in WebGL format

Tags: unity-game-engine, export, unity-webgl

Help please. I'm exporting the game to WebGL. Using a "Gzip" compressor. And when running in the local server, it gives such an error. How to fix it? (I have already tried to turn off the compressor did not help).

text error:
Unable to parse Build/grrrr.framework.js! The file is corrupt, or compression was misconfigured? (check Content-Encoding HTTP Response Header on web server)
[image: error]

[image: settings]

(I have already tried to turn off the compressor did not help).

Comment: Did you follow the setup of the webserver that unity outlines?

Comment: no. I started this game in local servere

Comment: And did you hit run in unity or just double click index.html?

Comment: I started it in unity and worked quietly. And html was launched through a local server.

Comment: Ok. So if unity ran it and made the temp server that would make no sense. If you have a local web server and its not the fake one unity makes during the run then you need to configure it